# when is the memory allocated for programs?

Tags: c++, memory, allocation

I understand the process of memory allocation for C++ programs. According to what I got from the internet, for C++ compilers, memory are allocated for the global variables and static variables at compiling time. While dynamically created variables (such as new/malloc operations) will be given space in the memory only when the executables are actually running. Correct me if I am wrong here.

So is it true that if the executable is never executed, then the part of memory previously allocated at compiling time for global & static variables will still and always sit there in the memory until the computer is shut down? What if we shut down the PC, and reboot it, then re-execute the executables? This time, there is no compiling process, when does the OS allocate memory for the global & static variables of this program? Is it in the system booting phase, or when the executable is actually executed?

Now extending this question to any general program in the PC. For example the Microsoft Word program. We did not code and compiled it by ourselves, we just installed it from its installation package, thus there is no compiling process in this situation (or maybe the installation process is actually the compiling process). Suppose these general programs also need space in the memory for static&global variables, when does the OS allocates memory for these programs? Is it when we power up and boot the OS, or when we actually execute the executables of these programs? If the OS pre-load all these static variables at boot time, that kind of explained why the OS booting process takes some time, but it seems to be a waste of memory resource if 90% of the programs installed in the system will not be executed each time the user powers up and use his PC.

Comment: No memory is allocated at compile-time. Memory allocations start at *run-time*.

Comment: I thought the question was clear, and related to programming, if a bit rambly and naive (but that is ok). There was obviously thought behind it, which is more than can be said for most of the questions here these days. Much better than "why does my program crash". I may be a bit biased though.

Comment: @JasonC: It's too broad. OP should read a bloomin' book. We can't teach all of how compilers work here. There may have been "thought behind it", but zero research.

Comment: Well, I put in my reopen vote. The rest is up to fate. Good luck, brave question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler essentially compiles all the static stuff and code into an image that is kept on disk, e.g. in exe files on Windows, etc.

When you run it, the operating system allocates some memory and basically copies this image into ram, then starts running the compiled code, which was also copied to ram.

Memory that you allocate dynamically in your program is allocated as your program executes.

No ram is allocated for your program at compile time. The statement "memory is allocated at compile time" is a conceptual simplification. What it *really* means is that the initial memory image, stored in the compiled file, is built at compile time. This won't be loaded into ram until the program is actually run.

This is very simplified but is the general gist. Check out the file format specifications for the binary file format on your system for some more interesting hints ([for example](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable)), among other things.